# Multiple forwardfor commands in HAProxy config

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, http, haproxy

In HAProxy, I would like to `forwardfor` everything except a few networks like below (multiple networks)

```
frontend  main
    bind         myip:5356-60000
    mode                 http
    option               http_proxy
    option forwardfor    except 127.0.0.0/8 #1st network
    option forwardfor    except 1.1.1.1/32 #2nd network
    option forwardfor    except 2.2.2.2/32 #3rd network
    option forwardfor    except 3.3.3.3/32 #4th network
    maxconn              950
    timeout              client  30s
    default_backend      mybackendserver
```

This doesn't work, instead of not forwarding ALL of the specified networks it only works on the last one (the 4th network).

Each `option forwardfor except my-network-here` command overwrites the previous one instead of appending them. How can I achieve forwarding everything except a whitelist of multiple networks?

Comment: maybe you can try `option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8 except 1.2.3.4/32 except 5.6.7.8`

Comment: I just tested @Aleksandar's suggestion and it appears to work; at least, it doesn't result in a syntax error.  It may also end up using the last `except ip/mask` reading from left to right - would need to test to confirm.

Comment: That solution doesn't error out, but it also _does not work_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a somewhat hacky solution, it was not my first choice but it works for my needs. In the haproxy config I am using an acl whitelist that contains all the ips that I do not wish to forwardfor. If the request comes from an ip that exists in the whitelist, haproxy will use a second backend that is identical to the first one, except that it does not forwardfor. I basically moved the forwardfor option to the backend portion instead of the frontend.

so,

```
    frontend  main
        bind         myip:5356-60000
        mode                 http
        option               http_proxy
        maxconn              950
        timeout              client  30s
        acl white_list_noforward src 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 etc..
        #explanation: if the ip is not found in the whitelist, use the backend_that_forwards, else, and the ip is in the whitelist use the backend_that_DOESNT_forward 
        use_backend backend_that_forwards if !white_list_noforward
        use_backend backend_that_DOESNT_forward if white_list_noforward  
        #default to the backend that forwards just in case something goes wrong
        default_backend      use_backend backend_that_forwards

   backend_that_forwards #forwards client ip
        mode        http
        option forwardfor    except 127.0.0.0/8 # <-- THIS forwards the real client ip except 127.0.0.0/8
        balance     roundrobin
        timeout     connect 5s
        timeout     server  5s
        server      static 127.0.0.1:80 # same server for both backends

  backend_that_DOESNT_forward #DOES NOT forward the client-ip (No option forwardfor is used here), used to handle all requests coming in from ips that I do not wish to forward for
       mode        http
       balance     roundrobin
       timeout     connect 5s
       timeout     server  5s
       server      static 127.0.0.1:80 # same server for both backends
```